# what is the area of the region bound by $f(x)=x^2$ , $g(x) = -x$ , $x=-1$, and $x=1$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm asked to find the area of the region bound by $f(x)=x^2$ , $g(x) = -x$ , $x=-1$, and $x=1$, as shown here:

[image: graph]

would you find this by just using

$\int _{-1}^1 [f(x)-g(x)]dx$

or would you divide it into two intervals , one where $g(x) ≥ f(x) $ and one where $f(x) ≥ g(x)$ and then use:

$Area = \int _{0}^1 [f(x)-g(x)]dx + \int _{-1}^0 [g(x)-f(x)]dx$ ?

Comment: Cannot you compute the area of every three parts of the natural decomposition of this domain? Which one would be difficult to compute?

Comment: it's not exactly an issue of being hard to compute, this is a multiple choices question in my book. my own result is one , but the book's results are 
$ a) \frac{1}{2}$   ,$ b)  \frac{5}{6}$  , $c) -  \frac{1}{2}$ , $d)  \frac{1}{3}$ ,and $e)  \sqrt{e} $. so I thought that there was something wrong with the way I was solving it

Comment: Well done for drawing a diagram. Now try reflecting the piece on the left-hand side in the vertical axis (which you wouldn't spot without a diagram, I think) and the answer is easy.. For multi choice you don't have to show detailed workings.

Comment: @MarkBennet the area then becomes 1, right?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't specify the area above the $x-$axis?

Comment: @MarkBennet no , it just asks for the area bound by the two given functions , and the vertical lines $ x=1$ and $x=-1$ . well tbh since $\sqrt{e}$ is one of the answers it's most likely a screw up on the book's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$Area=\int_{-1}^{0}(g(x)-f(x))dx+\left|\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx\right|+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

Comment: it's equal to 1 , right?